# Method does not exist: Deploying Cloud Endpoint

Tags: google-cloud-endpoints, google-kubernetes-engine

My spring boot project has a numerous number of rest APIs and to deploy using Cloud Endpoint, it throws error. Application runs in GKE.

Error shows **Method does not exists.** I have referred the issue and I am not using default root path for checking the status in openapi.yaml

Here is configuration:

**openapi.yaml**

```
# [START swagger]
swagger: "2.0"
info:
  description: "SPR API"
  title: "SPR API"
  version: "1.0.0"
host: "spr-api.endpoints.spr-mza-dev.cloud.goog"
# [END swagger]
schemes:
- "http"
paths:
  "/statuscheck":
    get:
      description: "Returns Status code"
      operationId: "status"
      parameters:
        - name: name
          in: query
          description: "Status verification"
          required: true
          type: string
      #produces:
      #- "application/json"
      responses:
        200:
          description: "Status 200"
```

**Deployment.yaml**

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: spr-api
spec:
  ports:
  - port: 80
    targetPort: 8081
    protocol: TCP
    name: http
  selector:
    app: spr-api
  type: LoadBalancer
---
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: spr-api
spec:
  replicas: 1
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: spr-api
    spec:
      containers:
      # [START esp]
      - name: esp
        image: gcr.io/endpoints-release/endpoints-runtime:1
        args: [
          "--http_port", "8081",
          "--backend", "127.0.0.1:8080",
          "--service", "spr-api.endpoints.spr-mza-dev.cloud.goog",
          "--rollout_strategy", "managed",
        ]
      # [END esp]
        ports:
          - containerPort: 8081
      - name: spr-api
        image: "gcr.io/spr-mza-dev/sprapis:latest"
        ports:
          - containerPort: 8080
```

**Whiling hitting endpoint I get bellow error:**

```
{
code: 5,
message: "Method does not exist.",
details: [
{
@type: "type.googleapis.com/google.rpc.DebugInfo",
stackEntries: [ ],
detail: "service_control"
}
]
}
```

Thanks for your valuable inputs.

Regards.

Answer (score 0):

It could be a *missmatch between your openapi.yaml that was used to configured your API into endpoints and your actual spring-boot API code*.

In my case I faced that same issue and the cause was that in my swagger file (OpenAPI) I missed a **basePath** configuration! My API code running inside GKE was expecting requests starting with the path `/api/v1` but this was not mapped into my endpoints configuration (swagger.yaml).

Check if the path displayed at **Method** columns into your endpoints console is the same is configured inside you application running into GKE. In my Method console was displaying only `/elements` not the full path `/api/v1/elements` and then after updating my OpenAPI configuration adding the BasePath it was solved.

References:

- https://swagger.io/docs/specification/2-0/api-host-and-base-path/
- https://cloud.google.com/endpoints/docs/openapi/troubleshoot-response-errors